Looking for the name of a SF/Fantasy series with a girl who would count all of her steps
I don't remember a huge amount about this series. I'm fairly sure it was a trilogy, and it had generic planets on the covers of the version/s I read.
In terms of story/characters that I vaguely remember:

There was a girl who was incredibly good with numbers; she would count her steps everywhere.
At some point, she may have done some magic that involved dividing by zero??
There was also a eunuch character (possibly a slave) who becomes a god.
At the end of the series, the two characters above end up married.
The eunuch character has a fight with someone and one of the two of them ends up with their throat crushed.

There were also at least two other pov characters but I really don't remember anything of them.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  When you say "generic planets" do you mean like planets in space?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters or places they visited?

I'd say I read this before 2012, around the same time as Brent Weeks' Night Angel trilogy.
For the planets, I think something like the moon on The Killing Moon, but taking up the whole cover space.
I don't recall any of the names of characters or places unfortunately.

Is the counting in the obsessive-compulsive disorder (OCD) style? If so, it might be one of Orson Scott Card's books Gloriously Bright.

Well, after a long search on Book Filter I found the book series... and then found that I already had it on my Good Reads collection...
Turns out I was blurring together two series from the same author - Russell Kirkpatrick.
The plot and characters are from the Broken Man trilogy, while the covers with planets were from the Fire of Heaven trilogy.

It's great that you found it!  You can improve your answer by including some quotes from the goodreads page that describe the series a bit, in case the link breaks in the future.

And you can self accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.
